# How to create a button for Python GUI to load data into Cassandra via .sh file choosing a .csv

Tags: python, bash, shell, csv, ubuntu

With this .sh I can load a .csv file into Apache Cassandra using DSBulk loader:

```
export PATH=/home/workstation/dsbulk-1.7.0/bin:$PATH

source ~/.bashrc

dsbulk load -url /home/workstation/ll/datatest.csv -k test_keyspace -t test_data  -delim "," -header false
```

Using the .sh showed, I'm creating a Python GUI to load the .csv data with a button. So, I've implemented the code below. I can load data with that button, but, how can I choose the .csv file which must be opened and loaded? I used a similar function in a different way but not to choose a file opened from the .sh.

This is the function of the button:

```
def Dataloader():
   
   subprocess.call('./tester.sh', shell=True)


button = Button(window, text=" Load data into APC ", bg="black", fg="white",command=Dataloader)
```

Some suggestion? Where am I going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I added this to the .sh ando so I can choose a file (.csv) but how can I use in te command  dsbulk load etc..?
file="$(zenity --title "Pick a file" --file-selection)"

Comment: it gives : Java.io.IOException: Error creating CSV parser for file: /home/workstation/ll/datatest.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

on the .sh must be written

```
echo "you selected $(zenity --file-selection)"
```

then, the action needed es: dsbulk....